# tkinter if else related issue of input and output

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, label, tkinter-entry

In my program i am using tkinter, the issue is with if else condition inside the function after clicking the submit button.

###### The if else statement is not giving correct output. i wanted this to be able to run multiple times with different value without rerunning the program.

```
    from tkinter import *
    main = Tk()

    def show_answer():
        Ans = int(num1.get())
        if Ans>5 or Ans <10:
            blank.config(text="this is between 5 and 10")
        else:
            blank.config(text="this is out of range")

    Label(main, text = "Enter Num 1:").grid(row=0)
    Label(main, text = "The Sum is:").grid(row=2)
    num1 = Entry(main)
    blank = Label(main,text="", width=25 )
    num1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    blank.grid(row=2, column=1)
    Button(main, text='Quit', command=main.destroy).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
    Button(main, text='Show', command=show_answer).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't you want an if with an and `if Ans>5 and Ans <10:` ?

Comment: @PandaBlue thanks very much..... what an idiot i am. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `or` unstead of `and`
try this :

```
if 5 <= Ans <= 10:
```